# Express JS app showing cannot find after deployment on cPanel while working fine on local

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel

Express App showing cannot find after deploying on cPanel. I have tried to sort out this issue also when I write server.listen() it works great but when I write app.listen() it gives cannot find message.

I tried default Node Js code (last 10 lines except app.listen() ) which works fine while app.listen() not working:

```
const express = require("express");
const multiparty = require('multiparty');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const morgan = require('morgan');
const { createHttpTerminator } = require('http-terminator');
const fs = require('fs');
const cors = require('cors');
const crypto = require('crypto');
require('dotenv').config();
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');


const {Product, Service, Home, HireMe } = require('./models/Product');

const app = express();

app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Home Page...!');
});

app.get('/offers', async (req, res) => {
    
  try {
    const result = await Product.find({});
    res.send("result");
  } catch (err) {
    res.send({ 'error': err.message });
  }
})



var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    var message = 'It works!\n',
        version = 'NodeJS ' + process.versions.node + '\n',
        response = [message, version].join('\n');
    res.end(app);
});
server.listen(); //It works
app.listen (); // Showing Cannot find message
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by prefixing the URL link (on which I created node JS on cPanel) to routes. Now it works great.

Comment: How can I prefix the url link. having the same issue here.